# Swift - Call completion handler from a second function

Tags: swift, api, asynchronous, alamofire, completionhandler

thanks for reading this, i hope you can understand my problem. Basically what i would like to do is this:

```
private func doGet(path:String, body:Dictionary, completion: @escaping (JSON?, Bool) -> Void) {
    completion(data, bool)
}

func getData(body){
    return doGet("/api/data", body: body)
}

// The function gets called in another class
getData(data){ (data, bool) 
    // do something with data
}
```

I know this code doesnt work but thats what i would like to do. I dont want to call doGet from the other class i want to have a function in between. Maybe this is not possible. Please let me know if i didnt make myself clear and thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getData` also needs to have a completion handler parameter, since it too returns the results asynchronously.

So, you'd have something like this:

```
getData(body: SomeType, completion: @escaping (Data, Bool) -> Void) {
   doGet(path: "/api/data", body: body) { (param1, param2) in
       // turns param1 and param2 into parameters to invoke 
       // the completion handler with
       completion(data, true)
   }
}
```